# How do I create a C++ program that passes command line arguments to a shell script?

Tags: c++

I have never used C++ before and my professor said this is supposed to be "very simple", but I can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char command[50];
  if (argc==2)
    system(command, "./findName.sh", argv[1]);
}  
return 0;
```

My shell script works when I run it by itself but I am not sure how to use a C++ program to run it. For the shell script, the user is supposed to enter a user ID like this:

```
./findName.sh userID
```

and the program returns the person's name from a file of names and user IDs like this:

```
LastName, FirstName
```

For the C++ program, it needs to pass the information the user enters to the shell script and return the same results.

As I said, I have never used C++ before so I don't know if any of this is right. It is a mix of things I have found online. Thank you for all of your help!!

Comment: `C++` is not really the kind of language you can cobble together bits you find laying around the internet. I suggest studying a *recommended* book methodically for a couple of hours a day. There are many bad books but these are recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I find to do this is to use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) as it allows you to *concatenate* stings easily.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string command = "./findName.sh";

    if(argc == 2)
        std::system((command + " " + argv[1]).c_str());
}
```

But to understand why this works you are going to need to [study some books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

First you need to compile the program before you can run it. If your source code file name is `progname.cpp` you should be able to use this command:

```
g++ -o progname progname.cpp
```

And then run the program like this:

```
./progname userID
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I try to run it though it says : "syntax error near unexpected token '(' in 'int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )' ". Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Abby.b This code works for me, I just re-tested it. Did you input everything exactly as I have it? Its best to cut/n/paste, every comma, bracket and parenthesis has to be exactly right.

Comment: I copied and pasted but that is what it gave me. I just tried again in a new file and it did the same thing.

Comment: @Abby.b Did you compile the program or are you trying to run the source code directly?

Comment: @Abby.b I added instructions to compile the program just in case you are trying to run the source code.

Comment: @Abby.b Ok. The reason I checked is because i get the same error you describe if I try to run the source code.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!! I think the problem was when I tried to compile it I didn't put in the -o. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

1) system("abc.sh " + para1 + " " + para2);
But this method have a limitation, the max length you can pass into is 
MAX_ARG_STRLEN is defined as 131072 bytes=32 pages of memory.

2) open a file and read all the value to the file
system("abc.sh < yourfile.txt");
This method is a bit indirect, but you can put unlimited size of value to sh
inside the sh, use a normal read from buf ( or keyboard )